# Замена кода кнопок телеофона

Tags: java, android, интерфейс

Мне бы хотелось заменить исполнение кода системных кнопок телефона, а именно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не про 2 нажатие на кнопку "назад", а например нажимая кнопку "назад", открываеться главная страница приложения,не смотря на место перебывания пользователя

Comment: а в чём проблема? Кнопку назад можно перехватить с помощью onBackPressed на активити например.

Comment: но по идеи такая задача решается правильной работой с навигационным стеком.

Comment: Так вам нужно описанное поведение или наоборот не нужно? Если нужно: `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` - добавить этот атрибут в манифест для каждой активности, которая должна возвращаться на главную и указать в нём имя класса главной активити

Comment: @woesss, можете записать, вы правы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` - добавить этот атрибут в манифест для каждой активности, которая должна возвращаться на главную и указать в нём имя класса главной активити